# React- update children but not immediate parent

Tags: reactjs

I've got a React component hierarchy that looks a little like this:

```
var A = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        /* stuff */
    }
});    
var B = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return dom.div(null, this.props.children);
    }
});    
var C = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return dom.div(null, B(null, A()));
    }
});
```

Essentially, C passes an A element to B as a child, and B subsequently renders it.

Now I'm in a position where I want to update the A element *but not B*. It's unclear to me what the semantics of shouldComponentUpdate are in this case. If I implement a shouldComponentUpdate in B, do I need to consider whether or not my children should update? Is it impossible to update the child without updating it's immediate parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update A but not B, you should actually describe A behaviour in it's own component - for example, subscribe to some third-party source of truth (Store in terms of [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/flux-overview.html) architecture) in A's `componentDidMount` hook.

This is the only way - if A has no control on it's own flow, it will update *only* on B (exectly parent) `render()` call - which you can already control by B's (and \ or it's parents') `shouldComponentUpdate`.