# React: How can I prevent the parent component re-rendering onmousemove state change when only the child component needs re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A parent component updates x,y properties in state onmousemove, these are then passed via props to a child component. Currently both the parent and the chid re-renders onmousemove; is there a way to prevent the re-render on the parent so that only the child re-renders? Example: The parent is the bounding area, the child is a custom cursor.

Comment: it's better to share a snippet for others to help

Comment: Just don't save the updated properties to parents state.

Comment: Are you facing any performance issues? If No then its fine. If yes then you can memo heavy components.

Comment: I don't think you can update a child component without updating the parent component. if you return `false` in  `shouldComponentUpdate` function, that specific component wont rerender. The only way is to keep x,y as a state to the child component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React- update children but not immediate parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474475/react-update-children-but-not-immediate-parent)

Comment: Thanks guys. No performance issues, I was just wondering. Basically I am counting each of my components renders and using shouldComponentUpdate to prevent unnecessary renders of any components that does not need to update onmousemove. The only one I couldn't optimise was the parent component...this re-renders with its child cursor component on mousemove due to its state change.
As I'm using the parent component as a bounding box for the cursor component the mouse capturing has to happen there, from here it seems there's no way of updating the cursor's local state.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the state(x,y coords) local to the child component.

Comment: The problem with this is the state handling will be in the parent component. Like onClick of parent div state must change.

Comment: You could update the parent state on click but not on mousemove

Comment: yes, this won't work. The child component is a cursor and needs updating on mousemove of the parent component that serves as the bounding box. The parent captures the mouse position and passes it to the cursor. I can't find a way to change the cursor's local state from within the parent event handler, the state change therefore happens on the parent triggering a re-render of both.